# Using MatrixCursor in unit test

Tags: android, android-testing

Im trying to test a helper class I wrote that interacts with cursor objects. I've written the test using a `MatrixCursor` to construct the cursor used for the tests but since `MatrixCursor` is built into the android framework it's not compatible with unit testing and needs to be mocked or used in an instrumented test. Is there any workaround? Is it possible to import `MatrixCursor` as a gradle test dependency?